# aspx can't get menber from aspx.cs which it inherit

Tags: c#, asp.net

These Code are some examples on the book 'pro asp.net 4.5' written by Adam freeman,Matthew MacDonald,Mario Szpuszta.

I create a new project and follow the book to write some codes.The last time I finish the page Listing.aspx, it worked just well. But next time I open this project and try to open this page, these errors suddenly came out.And there are some errors just like these in other pages.

These are the error codes

[image]

As you see, Listing.aspx can't get 'MaxPage' and 'CurrentPage' from Listing.aspx.cs, though these two variables have been already declared in Listing.aspx.cs and they are 'public'.And I have already check the class name and the namespace, they have no problem.

Actually 'MaxPage' can be fond through 'new SportsStore.Pages.Listing().MaxPage'.It seems like the Listing.aspx doesn't inherit the Listing.aspx.cs.Then I check the '.csproj' file, it seems no problem.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <Content Include="Controls\CategoryList.ascx" />
    <Content Include="Pages\CartView.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Pages\Listing.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Pages\Store.Master" />
    <None Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

...

```
<Compile Include="Pages\Listing.aspx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Listing.aspx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Pages\Listing.aspx.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Listing.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Then I even tried recreate the whole project, recreate each pages one by one, but the error still.

Here're files belong to this page.Including Listing.aspx, Listing.aspx.cs, Listing.aspx.designer.cs.

Listing.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Listing.aspx.cs" Inherits="SportsStore.Pages.Listing" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/Store.Master" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" runat="server">
    <div id="content">
        <%--<%
            foreach (SportsStore.Models.Product prod in GetProducts())
            {
                Response.Write("<div class='item'>");
                Response.Write(string.Format("<h3>{0}</h3>", prod.Name));
                Response.Write(prod.Description);
                Response.Write(string.Format("<h4>{0:c}</h4>", prod.Price));
                Response.Write(string.Format("<button name='add' type='submit' value='{0}'>Add to Cart</button>", prod.ProductID));
                Response.Write("</div>");
            }
            %>--%>
        <asp:Repeater ItemType="SportsStore.Models.Product" SelectMethod="GetProducts" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class='item'>
                    <h3><%# Item.Name %></h3>
                    <%# Item.Description %>
                    <h4><%# Item.Price.ToString("c") %></h4>
                    <button name='add' type='submit' value='<%# Item.ProductID %>'>Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    <div class="pager">
        <% for (int i = 1; i <= MaxPage; i++)
            {
                //Response.Write(string.Format("<a href='/Pages/Listing.aspx?page={0}' class='selected'>{0}</a>", i));
                string selectedCategory = (string)RouteData.Values["category"] ?? Request.QueryString["category"];
                RouteValueDictionary routeValueDic = new RouteValueDictionary() { { "page", i } };
                if (selectedCategory != null)
                {
                    routeValueDic.Add("category", selectedCategory);
                }
                string path = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, null, routeValueDic).VirtualPath;

                Response.Write(string.Format("<a href='{0}' {1}>{2}</a>", path, i == CurrentPage ? "class='selected'" : "", i));
            }
            %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Listing.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SportsStore.Models;
using SportsStore.Models.Repository;
using SportsStore.Pages.Helpers;

namespace SportsStore.Pages
{
    public partial class Listing : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Repository myRepository = new Repository();
        private int pageSize = 4;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["add"], out int selectedProductId))
                {
                    Product selectedProduct = myRepository.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == selectedProductId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (selectedProduct != null)
                    {
                        SessionHelper.GetCart(Session).AddItem(selectedProduct, 1);
                        SessionHelper.Set(Session, SessionKey.RETURN_URL, Request.RawUrl);

                        Response.Redirect(RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "cart", null).VirtualPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            return FilterProducts().OrderBy(prod => prod.Price).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }

        public int CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                //int page = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out page) ? page : 1;
                int page = GetPageFromRequest();
                return page > MaxPage ? MaxPage : page;
            }
        }

        public int MaxPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)FilterProducts().Count() / pageSize);
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<Product> FilterProducts()
        {
            string selectedCategory = (string)RouteData.Values["category"] ?? Request.QueryString["category"];
            return selectedCategory == null ? myRepository.Products : myRepository.Products.Where(x => x.Category == selectedCategory);
        }

        private int GetPageFromRequest()
        {
            int page;
            string reqValue = (string)RouteData.Values["page"] ?? Request.QueryString["page"];
            return reqValue != null && int.TryParse(reqValue, out page) ? page : 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Listing.aspx.designer.cs

```
namespace SportsStore.Pages {


    public partial class Listing {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding and closing and reopening Visual Studio?

Comment: I try that just now. I even try run code analysis.But the errors still exist

Comment: just recreated based on your code and both properties resolve for me.  They didn't at first though.  Because I didn't have all your code (product class, repo, etc.), I had to start commenting out stuff until the solution built.  Can you confirm the solution builds successfully in VS?

Comment: If it is building, one other thing you can try is doing what David suggested, but also deleting the obj directory from the solution folder.

Comment: I'm already found the real error but thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the real error.
I was inspired by another question on stackoverflow. So I choose Build Only instead of Build + IntelliSense in the Error List.Then those 'the name does not exist' errors gone, and I saw another error point to these code

code image link: [error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOOXK.png)

I have no right to publish an image, so please open this link.Or you can just see codes I put below

```
        if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["add"], out int selectedProductId))
        {
            Product selectedProduct = myRepository.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == selectedProductId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (selectedProduct != null)
            {
                SessionHelper.GetCart(Session).AddItem(selectedProduct, 1);
                SessionHelper.Set(Session, SessionKey.RETURN_URL, Request.RawUrl);

                Response.Redirect(RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "cart", null).VirtualPath);
            }
        }
```

As you see, the variable selectedProductId was inline declared inside the if().But I use it inside if{}.Though it'll be actually used only when it's declared successfully, the vs2017 still consider it as a error. I think that maybe vs2017 havn't considered that.

I said the project just worked well last time because I declared the variable selectedProductId before the 'if'.And I made that change because the vs2017 give a hint for optimizing code.I just clicked the button and didn't think too much and closed the project, so next time I opened the project, it didn't worked.

Sometimes vs show some errors which are not the real errors.The real errors are before those, but the vs just can't locate them. I found the issue several times when I was doing asp projects.It's very annoyed because it is very hard to locate the error if you type a lot of codes.Hope microsoft can fit it as soon as possible.